# Incompatible Android app in PlayStore

Tags: android, screen

My app is a "normal" one that doesn't require any special screen size or density. Just the regular one with activities and their layouts with the base views. Not any drawing or special graphics.

For some reason I don't remember (and I really regret) I added the next ***compatible-screens*** code to my Manifest. Since then I am finding that some devices (I cannot specify which) are not compatible with my app anymore. PlayStore will not let them update (well, actually PlayStore doesn't display my app on those, and if the users look for it manually then it says it is not compatible).
I cannot remove the code and upload my app again because PlayStore doesn't allow me to remove the ***compatible-screens*** entry.

So, the question is: 
Is this code right? Do I have to add any more possibilities to fit every screen (including tablets)?

The last user that complaint had a Samsung Galaxy Star GT-S5282

This is the code:

```
<compatible-screens>

    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480"/> #xxhdpi HTC One, S4...

    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" /> #xxhdpi HTC One, S4...

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" /> #xxhdpi HTC One, S4...

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" /> #xxhdpi HTC One, S4...

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: **"I cannot remove the code and upload my app again because PlayStore doesn't allow me to remove the compatible-screens entry."** : I'm not sure I understand that statement. As long as your package name is the same and it's signed with the same key, you should be able to modify your app in any way you choose.

Comment: post your android manifest.xml to have more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increment the version number and build number

Comment: Also can you give the exact message you are getting

Comment: Yes, incrementing the versionCode integer would be my guess too. Google Play probably thought that he was trying to publish two different apks under the same version number (thus requiring that he specifies the difference in screens from the first apk, otherwise the upload of a separate apk with the same features wouldn't make any sense).

Answer (score 1):

Your app must require add some hardware elements (if your app are currently using it) with `required="false"`, not only the `<compatible-screens>` into your `manifest.xml`

```
  <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature
             android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
             android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" 
            android:required="false" />
```

More info:

**[Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html